# addEventListener memory leak due to frames

Tags: javascript, memory, greasemonkey, addeventlistener

I have a GreaseMonkey script that works on a site that uses frames as an integral part of its interface.  This script leaks memory like a sieve, and I believe it is due to my use of addEventListener within one of the frames.  Quite simply, I attach a variety of event listeners, then the frame reloads and I attach the event listeners, and then the frame reloads, around and around for hundreds or possibly thousands of iterations as you interact with various elements in this frame or others.  By the end of it, Firefox has gone from ~300M of memory to as much as 2G (or crashes before it gets there).

I read somewhere that doing a full page reload would allow FireFox's garbage collection routines to kick in and recover all the memory from orphaned event handlers, and sure enough when I hit F5 after my script has run for a while, within about 10 seconds the memory is back down to 300M.  Unfortunately this breaks a different frame in the site (a very popular chat window), so while it does seem to confirm my suspicion that addEventListener is to blame, it's not really an option as a solution.

Is there something else I can do to free up the memory properly without forcing a full page refresh?

(Currently using GM 1.5 and FF 17, but the issue has existed since GM 0.8/FF 4 or thereabouts.)

Comment: instead of adding your event listeners from within the frame (every time the frame reloads), just add the listeners once in the code outside the frame.  Define functions inside the frame corresponding to each event you want to handle, and have each event handler (outside the frame) call the appropriate function inside the frame.

Comment: @Lee, would you be willing to sketch out how that code would look?  Also how would I be able to handle elements that come and go occasionally?  Essentially, the pane is a status pane, and as your status changes new elements appear, which I then attach some events to.  (There are also permanent elements, and I'm definitely looking forward to trying your approach out. :-) )

Comment: Lee's approach won't work if it's cross domain. ... It's not clear that `addEventListener` is a/the problem, but there is possibly a jQuery workaround, if you are open to jQuery.  What happens when you use the site for at least 30 minutes with the Greasemonkey scripts disabled?

Comment: @Brock, all the activity is within a single domain.  I am definitely open to jQuery.  When I use the site without GM enabled, there is no leakage at all.

Comment: Also I'm entirely open to any other troubleshooting techniques you can recommend for narrowing down the source of the problem.  :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without seeing your complete script, or a [***Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example***](http://sscce.org/), we can't be sure of what is going on.  It may be that `addEventListener` is not the problem.

Here are some strategies for better code, with fewer memory leaks:

1. Inline/anonymous functions *are* often a culprit, especially with event handlers.

   **Poor / Leaky:**

   ```
   elem.onclick = function () {/*do something*/};
   elem.addEventListener ("click", function() {/*do something*/}, false);
   $("elem").click ( function () {/*do something*/} );
   ```

   **Not leaky and also easier to maintain:**

   ```
   elem.onclick = clickHandler;
   elem.addEventListener ("click", clickHandler, false);
   $("elem").click (clickHandler);

   function clickHandler (evt) {
       /*do something*/
   }
   ```

   Note that for userscripts you should [avoid `onclick`, etc. anyway.](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.232:_Event_Handlers)
2. Likewise do not use JS on HTML attributes.  EG don't use `<span onclick="callSomeFunction()">`, etc.
3. Minimize the code that runs in iframes to only that code you explicitly want.

   1. Use the `@include`, `@exclude`, and `@match` directives to block as many unwanted iframes as possible.
   2. [Wrap all code that doesn't need to run in iframes in a block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Prevent_Execution_in_Frames) like so:

      ```
      if (window.top === window.self) {
        // Not in a frame
      }
      ```
4. Do not use `innerHTML`.
5. For lots of elements, or elements that come and go with AJAX, do not use `addEventListener()` or jQuery's `.bind()`, `.click()`, etc.
   This replicates the listener across, potentially, thousands of nodes.

   Use [jQuery's `.on()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=on).  That way the listener is attached only once and triggers appropriately via bubbling.  (Note that in some rare-ish cases `.on()` can be blocked by the page's javascript.)

   In your case, you probably want something like:

   ```
   $(document).on ("click", "YOUR ELEM SELECTOR", clickHandler);

   function clickHandler (evt) {
       /*do something*/
   }
   ```
6. To avoid surprise circular references or orphaned items, use jQuery to add or remove elements, rather than direct DOM methods like `createElement()`, `appendChild()`, etc.
   jQuery is designed/tested to minimize such things.
7. Beware of overusing [`GM_setValue()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue).  It easily can use lots of global resources or cause a script instance to crash.

   1. For same-domain values, use `localStorage`.
   2. Do not use `GM_setValue()` to store anything but strings.  For anything else, use a serializer such as [`GM_SuperValue`](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/107941).  Even innocent looking integers can cause the default `GM_setValue()` to crash.
   3. Rather than store lots of small variables, it may be better to wrap them in an object and store *that* with one of the serializers.
8. Always check return values and assume that elements can be missing:
   This is **poor** (and, alas, typical):

   ```
   $("selector").text($("selector").text().match(/foo=([bar]+)/)[1]);
   ```

   **Better:**

   ```
   var salesItemDiv    = $("selector");
   var fooMatch        = salesItemDiv.text ().match (/\bfoo\s*=\s*([bar]+)\b/i);
   if (fooMatch  &&  fooMatch.length > 1) {
       salesItemDiv.text ( fooMatch[1] );
   }
   ```

   possibly followed by:

   ```
   salesItemDiv = fooMatch = null;
   ```

   see below.
9. Beware of recursive / inline `setTimeout()` calls.  Use `setInterval()` for repeated timing.  Just like with event handlers, do not use inline/anonymous functions.
10. Run your code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).
11. Avoid `eval()` and [auto/hidden `eval()` invocations](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.231:_Auto-eval_Strings).
12. Set variables to `null` when you are done with them. [See this, for example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/768872/331508)
13. Reference: ["Do you know what may cause memory leaks in JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/170415/331508)
14. [Additional reading on JS memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20%2btitle:memory%20%2btitle:leaks)
15. [Mozilla *Performance: Leak Tools*](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Performance:Leak_Tools)

Comment: Gadzooks!  I cannot imagine that my script would not improve dramatically after following only 1/4 of the advice given.  :-)  (I certainly know that it suffers from some of the issues that you list.)  If I still have issues with it (and it is quite a behemoth, unfortunately) I shall put together the SSCCE that you request, but I'll make that a separate question.