# Removing DOM nodes with proper GC (no leaks)

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools

### The problem

Adding nodes, while removing the old ones from the DOM, doesn't discard the old nodes from memory. (not all of them at least, without apparent reason).

### How to see this happening

*(you already know this but anyway..)*
right click the output area and inspect using Chrome **developer tools**.
Click on the **Timeline** tab and then at the circle (dot) on the upper left side to start recording.

now click on the body element, and it will start adding and removing items every *300ms* 

(the removed nodes should be garbage collected).

Stop the recording, extend the data-sampling zone to maximum, and you will see on the bottom half of the screen, in green, the nodes. the expected graph would be going up and down (where down means nodes have been discarded properly by the GC).

### Test pages

These 2 test pages are very primitive. of course in real life developers use templates which generates huge amount of text which should be converted into DOM and injected into the page, therefor the number of live DOM nodes in memory should be kept low, and removed ones *must* be discarded.

**with jQuery** - http://jsbin.com/lamigucuqogi/2/edit - After about 40 seconds the GC is getting crazy and stops collecting removed nodes, which causes inflation.

[image]

**Naive way** - http://jsbin.com/riref/2/edit - Also it seems nodes aren't being removed in a satisfying rate, and the number keeps growing and growing...

[image]

### Question

Why is this happening, and how should one properly remove NODES so inflation won't occur?

Comment: I don't get that result on my machine. Are you sure it's not a race condition? Do you get the same result with a longer interval?

Comment: I've tried for 1 minute. it reaches 100,000 nodes. I think in real apps that would be pretty crazy. I mean, why aren't them being collected as they are removed? and why are they being collected on the first example, then mysteriously stop being collected. What result are you seeing? are they being collected?

Comment: Which version of chrome? I'm on Chrome 37 64-bit (Linux). Yes, mine are being collected.

Comment: Version 37.0.2062.124 m / Windows 7 64bit

Comment: @squint - interesting. could you post your graph here? http://snapnote.io/

Comment: I'm running it again. Just want to make sure. I'll let it run for a few minutes this time.

Comment: Yes, I've tried letting it run for more than 1 minute (like 5) and it did collect them. seems like the way it collects element is not consistent so I was thinking it stopped, while actually it just took more time after the first few clears

Comment: That's interesting. Sounds like you've got it figured out then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mistaken. If you leave the example running for a significant period of time, then use the garbage can icon in the Dev Tools timeline to force a garbage collection you will observe that the nodes are freed.

Like any other JavaScript object, DOM nodes become eligible for GC when they become unreachable from [GC Roots](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling#terminology-and-fundamentals). Provided you do not retain any other references to removed nodes (in an array, for example), they become unreachable once removed from the main document.

However, they are not garbage collected immediately - a GC run can take time, during which the main browser thread is blocked, so it only runs periodically. What you are seeing is a period during which the JavaScript engine has decided not to run the garbage collector. You shouldn't be concerned by this - your code *does* allow the garbage collector to free memory when it eventually runs.

Highly recommended viewing - [Addy Osmani's memory management masterclass](http://addyosmani.com/blog/video-javascript-memory-management-masterclass/).

Comment: I don't understand. why would I want to clean the GC manually from within the dev tools? this won't prove anything. the GC must collect the removed DOM nodes by itself automatically. Also, this is not a answer, but a comment

Comment: Your premise seems to be that removed nodes are not garbage collected. This can be tested by triggering a manual GC event. When you do this, the removed nodes _are_ collected. Your code is perfectly fine. You should not be concerned about _when_ the JS engine decides to GC, just that your code enables it to free memory effectively when it does run. It is an answer because it explains that the problem is not caused by your code, which could solve a similar issue for another user in the future.